# Subring is not necessarily ideal, where to start?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

I am very new at algebra and currently studying at ring. Now I can find the explanation of **"Subring is not necessarily ideal"** from

> https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subring_is_not_necessarily_Ideal

but I still do not understand. Can someone explain it to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it helps to clarify the definitions. So a subring of a ring $R$ is a subset $S$ of $R$ preserving the structure of the ring (see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subring).

Now for an ideal, say $I$ of a ring $R$ we have the property, that 
$$\forall x \in I ~\forall r \in R ~~ x \cdot r \in I$$
(see for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory) for a definition of ideal).

So a subring does not have to have this property (by definition), which is used in the proof https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subring_is_not_necessarily_Ideal.